# Getting window owner names via CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo in Rust

Tags: macos, rust, core-foundation

I am trying to get the window owner names via CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo in Rust. So far I have managed to get the CFDictionaryRef but I am unable to use the right pointers for **CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent**.

This is the method signature: https://docs.rs/CoreFoundation-sys/0.1.4/CoreFoundation_sys/dictionary/fn.CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent.html

```
const options: CGWindowListOption = kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly + kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements;
const ptr_window_list_info: CFArrayRef = unsafe { CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, kCGNullWindowID) as CFArrayRef };

const count = unsafe { CFArrayGetCount(ptr_window_list_info) };

for i in 0..count-1 {
    let dic_ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(ptr_window_list_info, i) as CFDictionaryRef;
    //let key = CFString::new("kCGWindowOwnerName");
    let b = CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent(dic_ref, ?, ?);
    println!("window owner name: {}", value);
}
```

I am new to Rust and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent` looks like this:

`Boolean CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent(CFDictionaryRef theDict, const void *key, const void **value);`

In core_foundation, it looks like this:

```
pub unsafe extern "C" fn CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent(
    theDict: CFDictionaryRef, 
    key: *const c_void, 
    value: *mut *const c_void
) -> Boolean
```

I believe the key wants to be `CFStringRef`; in C there is a macro to make that easier (`CFSTR("cstring")`), here we must use a slightly longer form:

```
let c_key = CString::new("kCGWindowOwnerName").unwrap();
let cf_key = unsafe { 
    CFStringCreateWithCString(std::ptr::null(), c_key.as_ptr(), kCFStringEncodingUTF8) 
};
```

That gives us `CFStringRef`, in core_foundation it's defined like this:

`pub type CFStringRef = *const __CFString;`

It's already a `*const` pointer, just not the type we need. You can transmute to `c_void` instead:

`let key_ptr: *const c_void = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(cf_key) };`

The value argument just wants a raw double pointer to store the result. Create a null pointer:

`let mut value: *const c_void = std::ptr::null();`

And pass a mutable reference to it (`&mut value`) to get `*mut *const c_void`.

---

There are a few mistakes and oddities in your rust code. Here is a commented, working example:

```
use core_graphics::display::*;
use core_foundation::string::*;
use std::ffi::{ CStr, CString, c_void };

fn main() {
    // CGWindowListOption is a bitmask, combine the flags with bitwise OR
    const OPTIONS: CGWindowListOption = kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements;
    // No need to specify the type or use 'as'; CFArrayRef is the return type from CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo
    let window_list_info = unsafe { CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(OPTIONS, kCGNullWindowID) };
    // Don't use const here, CFArrayGetCount returns CFIndex (long)
    let count: i64 = unsafe { CFArrayGetCount(window_list_info) };

    for i in 0..count-1 {
        // Here we need the 'as', CFArrayGetValueAtIndex just returns void*
        let dic_ref = unsafe { CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(window_list_info, i) as CFDictionaryRef };

        // Create a CString from the key name we are interested in
        let c_key = CString::new("kCGWindowOwnerName").unwrap();
        // Create a CFString, needs to be released with `CFRelease`. I leave that as an exercise for the reader.
        let cf_key = unsafe { CFStringCreateWithCString(std::ptr::null(), c_key.as_ptr(), kCFStringEncodingUTF8) };

        // cf_key is a CFStringRef, which is a type alias to *const __CFString
        // We transmute it into *const c_void since that is what CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent wants
        let key_ptr: *const c_void = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(cf_key) };

        // A raw void* to hold the result
        let mut value: *const c_void = std::ptr::null();

        if unsafe { CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent(dic_ref, key_ptr, &mut value) != 0 } {
            // CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent returned true; that means value must point to a CFStringRef
            let cf_ref = value as core_foundation::string::CFStringRef;
            // Get a pointer to a C-string buffer with the characters from the CFString
            let c_ptr = unsafe { CFStringGetCStringPtr(cf_ref, kCFStringEncodingUTF8) };

            // The value may be null; don't pass it to CStr::from_ptr
            if c_ptr.is_null() { continue; }

            // Wrap the pointer in a rust CStr so we can convert a str
            let c_value = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(c_ptr) };
            println!("{}", c_value.to_str().unwrap());
        }
    }
}
```

---

For reference, here is the same example in C:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        CGWindowListOption options = kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements;
        CFArrayRef windows = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, kCGNullWindowID);

        CFIndex count = CFArrayGetCount(windows);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            CFDictionaryRef windowDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(windows, i);
            CFStringRef key = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "kCGWindowOwnerName", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
            const void* value = nil;

            if (CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent(windowDict, key, &value) == YES)
            {
                const char* c_value = CFStringGetCStringPtr(value, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

                NSLog(@"window: %s", c_value);
            }

            CFRelease(key);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Disclaimer** I am also relatively new to rust and this may not be the idiomatic solution

Comment: Thank you for this super detailed answer. One question, what is the different of using isize vs i64 for the loop?

Comment: No difference AFAIK; I was just porting the C version and the return type from `CFArrayGetCount` is `CFIndex`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to TheNextman's answer, I have modified the code to avoid the usage of transmute.

```
use core_graphics::display::*;
use core_foundation::string::*;
use core_foundation::number::*;
use core_foundation::base::*;
use std::ffi::{ CStr, c_void };

fn main() {
    const OPTIONS: CGWindowListOption = kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements;
    let window_list_info = unsafe { CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(OPTIONS, kCGNullWindowID) };
    let count = unsafe { CFArrayGetCount(window_list_info) };

    for i in 0..count {

        let dic_ref = unsafe { CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(window_list_info, i as isize) as CFDictionaryRef };

        let key = CFString::new("kCGWindowOwnerName");
        let mut value: *const c_void = std::ptr::null();

        if unsafe { CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent(dic_ref, key.to_void(), &mut value) != 0 } {

            let cf_ref = value as CFStringRef;
            let c_ptr = unsafe { CFStringGetCStringPtr(cf_ref, kCFStringEncodingUTF8) };
            if !c_ptr.is_null() {
                let c_result = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(c_ptr) };
                let result = String::from(c_result.to_str().unwrap());
                println!("window owner name: {}", result)
            }

        }

    }

    unsafe {
        CFRelease(window_list_info as CFTypeRef)
    }
}
```

Comment: `key.to_void()` < Nice!

Comment: You also made sure to release the result of `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`, which my answer missed

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you stumble upon this issue as well. Some entries for `kCGWindowOwnerName` are not a valid simple `CFString`, means after conversion you end up in having a null pointer.

To verify this, you can run this little c program:

```c
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>

// compile as such:
//  clang -framework carbon get-win.c -o get-win

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    CGWindowListOption options = kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements;
    CFArrayRef windows = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, kCGNullWindowID);
    CFIndex count = CFArrayGetCount(windows);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        CFDictionaryRef windowDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(windows, i);
        CFStringRef key = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "kCGWindowOwnerName", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
        const void *value = nil;

        if (CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent(windowDict, key, &value) == 1) {
            const char *c_value = CFStringGetCStringPtr(value, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
            if( c_value == NULL ) {
                // this is the very strange case, where a window owner name c_value is null, but `CFShow(value)`
                // yields a string, just without the regular quotation marks
                // like Finder vs "Finder"
                CFShow(value);
                CFShowStr(value);   // tells: This is an NSString, not CFString
            } else {
                printf("kCGWindowOwnerName = %s\n", c_value);
                printf("-- Details about the string:");
                CFShowStr(value);
                printf("-- End of Details\n\n");
            }
        }

        CFRelease(key);
    }
    CFRelease(windows);

    return 0;
}
```

I did not yet figure out, how to convert a `NSString*` to a `CFString*` or to `char*`.
If you know how to do this in c (not objective-c) leave a please comment.

Comment: in case someone needs a solution in rust, I ended up checking it like this:
https://github.com/sassman/t-rec-rs/blob/15c66a9a96bfe39205a6f5de12b8ac0b55cfe47f/src/macos/window_id.rs#L105

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, to save more people.

```
use std::ffi::{c_int, c_void, CString};

use core_foundation::{
    base::TCFType,
    dictionary::{CFDictionaryGetValue, __CFDictionary},
    number::{kCFNumberIntType, CFNumberGetValue, CFNumberRef},
    string::{kCFStringEncodingUTF8, CFStringCreateWithCString, CFStringGetCString},
};
use core_graphics::display::*;

#[derive(serde::Serialize)]
pub struct WindowInfo {
    pub hwnd: i32,
    pub title: String,
    pub x: i32,
    pub y: i32,
    pub width: i32,
    pub height: i32,
}

// I have almost no prior knowledge of the macOS API, and there are very few Rust examples about macOS.
// Writing this code is like playing the Shawshank Redemption.
// Thanks for the company of ChatGPT.
pub fn get_window_list() -> Vec<WindowInfo> {
    let mut window_info_vec: Vec<WindowInfo> = Vec::new();

    // CGWindowListOption is a bitmask, combine the flags with bitwise OR
    const OPTIONS: CGWindowListOption = kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly;
    // No need to specify the type or use 'as'; CFArrayRef is the return type from CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo
    let window_list_info = unsafe { CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(OPTIONS, kCGNullWindowID) };
    // Don't use const here, CFArrayGetCount returns CFIndex (long)
    let count = unsafe { CFArrayGetCount(window_list_info) };
    println!("{}", count);

    for i in 0..count {
        let dic_ref = unsafe { CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(window_list_info, i) as CFDictionaryRef };

        let mut window_id: c_int = 0;
        let num_ref = get_cfdict_val("kCGWindowNumber", dic_ref);
        unsafe {
            CFNumberGetValue(
                num_ref as CFNumberRef,
                kCFNumberIntType,
                &mut window_id as *mut c_int as *mut c_void,
            )
        };

        let name_ref = get_cfdict_val("kCGWindowOwnerName", dic_ref);
        let owner_name = cf_ref_to_string(name_ref);

        let val = get_cfdict_val("kCGWindowBounds", dic_ref);
        let rect_cf =
            unsafe { CFDictionary::wrap_under_get_rule(val as *const __CFDictionary) };
        let rect = CGRect::from_dict_representation(&rect_cf).unwrap();

        
        println!("window_id:{}", window_id);
        println!("owner_name:{}", owner_name);
        println!(
            "x:{},y:{},w:{},h:{}",
            rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height
        );
        window_info_vec.push(WindowInfo{
            hwnd: window_id,
            title: owner_name,
            x: rect.origin.x as i32,
            y: rect.origin.y as i32,
            width: rect.size.width as i32,
            height: rect.size.height as i32,
        })
    }

    window_info_vec
}
enter code here
```

You can find it in my project [scrcpy-mask](https://github.com/AkiChase/scrcpy-mask)